# Convert character matrix to numeric matrix to avoid NAs introduced by coercion

Tags: r

I have a 59 (columns) by 32514 (rows) matrix. Most of the data are `character`, and the structure of (a subset of) the matrix is as follows:

```
Event Time  Receipt Time    Device      Logger     Version     Device Vendor    
2013/09/30  2013/09/30  10.6.10.22   Events Local     0        Microsoft Window
```

I have stored the data in a matrix using R for processing. I am trying to do clustering using Kmeans, but am getting the following error:

```
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In kmeans(Data1, 5, iter.max = 10) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

As my data are in character format, the error `NAs introduced by coercion` is generated. I have tried to convert the data to numeric form with the following methods, but am still getting the same error.

```
Data1 <- as.numeric(as.character(Data))

Data1 <- as.matrix(sapply(Data, as.numeric))  

Data1 <- matrix(as.numeric(unlist(Data)),nrow=nrow(Data))
```

I have also tried to convert character into numeric column by column, but all data are converted into `NA`.

What is the correct method to convert my data to numeric?

Comment: What should be a numeric representation of, e.g.,  `"Events Local"` or `"Microsoft Window"`?

Comment: Perhaps you want to treat some of your data as factors, in which case you could represent factor levels by integers. For example: `d <- as.data.frame(m); d[, 3:6] <- apply(d[, 3:6], 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.factor(x)))`.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein I would like to convert "Events Local" or "Microsoft Window" etc. data into numeric form. Sample contains only few field, actual data contains 59 columns and most of them contains data as character. Numeric representation of "Events Local" such as "1" etc. Different event takes different numeric values. Main objective is to cluster similar kind of events based on 59 columns data.

Comment: @jbaums I tried as you suggested, it gives error like "dim(X) must have a positive length". Can you please let me know whether I need to specify X value in function(x). I tried using "Data1 <- matrix(as.numeric(unlist(Data)),nrow=nrow(Data))" but all columns data converted into "NA".

Comment: Don't substitute anything for `x`. If your matrix is the object `Data`, then try the following, verbatim: `d <- as.data.frame(Data); d[, 3:6] <- apply(d[, 3:6], 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.factor(x)))`. This would convert columns 3 through 6 to numbers corresponding to factor levels.